# Possible to blit images with alpha mask onto transparent surface?

Tags: c++, image, sdl

I am trying to do just that. I have an image of various tiles of an explosion in my game. I am trying to preprocess the explosion tiles and create the image and then blit it onto the screen.

Here is the tile sheet with the alpha mask:[Explosion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQh4v.png)

Now, I want to blit these and have them maintain their alpha transparency onto a surface which I can then render.

Here is my code:

```
SDL_Surface* SpriteManager::buildExplosion(int id, SDL_Surface* image, int size)
{
    // Create the surface that will hold the explosion image
    SDL_Surface* explosion = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, size * 32 , size * 32, 32, 0, 0, 0, 255 );

    // Our source and destination surfaces
    SDL_Rect srcrect;
    SDL_Rect dstrect;

    int parentX = sprites[id].x;
    int parentY = sprites[id].y;
    int middle = size / 2;

    // Create the first image
    srcrect.x = sprites[id].imgBlockX * 32; // default for now
    srcrect.y = sprites[id].imgBlockY * 32; // default for now
    srcrect.w = 32;
    srcrect.h = 32;

    // Get the location it should be applied to
    dstrect.x = middle * 32;
    dstrect.y = middle * 32;
    dstrect.w = 32;
    dstrect.h = 32;

    // Apply the texture
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, &srcrect, explosion, &dstrect);

    errorLog.writeError("Applying surface from x: %i y: %i to x: %i y:%i", srcrect.x, srcrect.y, dstrect.x, dstrect.y);

    // Iterate through each explosion
    for(int i = 0; i < sprites[id].children.size(); i++)
    {
        // Get the texture source
        srcrect.x = 0;  // default for now
        srcrect.y = 0;  // default for now
        srcrect.w = 32;
        srcrect.h = 32;

        // Get the location it should be applied to
        dstrect.x = sprites[id].children[i].x - parentX * 32;
        dstrect.y = sprites[id].children[i].y - parentY * 32;
        dstrect.w = 32;
        dstrect.h = 32;

        // Apply the texture
        SDL_BlitSurface(image, &srcrect, explosion, &dstrect);
    }

    //return img;
    return explosion;
}
```

I suspect it has to do with this line but I am really at a loss:

```
SDL_Surface* explosion = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, size * 32 , size * 32, 32, 0, 0, 0, 255 );
```

The SDL_Surface called image is the image I linked above just to make that clear. If anyone sees the error of my ways, many thanks!

My problem: The code above does either blits a completely invisible surface or a black surface with the images on them.

I guess I am curious if it possible to do what I described above and if I can modify this code to make that work.

Comment: Was there supposed to be an error message included with your question? You don't seem to have said exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: @Satchmo Have you read this: http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_SetAlpha ?